# Factorization of 5th polynomial with Wolfram-Mathematica

Tags: equation-solving, polynomials, parametric-functions, factorization

I have a very complicated 5th-degree polynomial form. Using the factor function in Wolfram is impossible to make it because of the high degree. I just want to know that is it possible to factor as I showed Fig-II. Can anybody help with this issue?

The polynomial form is;

```
(1 + L/R s + (2 C L + 2 C Subscript[L, m]) s^2 + ((
2 C L Subscript[L, m] + C L^2)/R) s^3 + 2 C^2 L s^4 Subscript[L, m] + (C^2 L^2  Subscript[L, m])/R s^5)
```

[image] **Fig-I**

**Fig-II**[image]

[image] **Fig-III**

Comment: Edit your question to include the code for the polynomial in a copy and paste-able form (`InputForm`) so that we can paste it into a notebook.

Comment: @Bob Hanlon I put the code of polynomial. Is it okey?

Comment: No, it does not factor that way. No idea what is meant by the remark "[u]sing the factor function in Wolfram is impossible to make it because of the high degree", but it does not correspond to the actual situation.

Comment: Why do you think that your polynomial can be factored into a linear factor and two quadratic factors in variable `s`?

Comment: Define a second polynomial of the desired form, e.g., `poly2 = (1 + a*s) (1 + b*s + c*s^2) (1 + d*s + e*s^2)` Equate their coefficients, i.e., `eqns = Thread[CoefficientList[poly1, s] == CoefficientList[poly2, s]]` If a solution to these equations exists, you have your result. However, this system failed to return a result in the amount of time that I was willing to give it.

Comment: @creidhne Not only reduce the degree of polynomial. I need to make the polynomial format like Fig II and try to find wp and Q in terms of L, C, Lm.

Comment: @Bob Hanlon Thank you, it is very good approach and I tried to run in Wolfram. But I want to find a,b,c,d,e in terms of R, L, C, Lm.  I attached the code and result in the above.

Comment: @Somos it is related to transfer function.

Comment: @BobHanlon The Wolfram could find a,b,c,d,e via Solve function

Comment: @ Bob Hanlon it does not work, it is too complicated for the Wolfrom.